# AzureMap : Real Time Alert pop up

Tags: azure-maps

I am new to AzureMap with limited knowledge of JavaScript and looking help in getting the real time alert based on some random flag during the fleet movement based on the co ordinates .

I tried multiple sources to design it like followed Sample code [enter link description here](https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/)

[image]

My requirement is :

Pip should pop up or appear only on arrival of the fleet (truck) .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To verify, when the truck gets to the end of the line you want to open a popup. I'm assuming you have a constant flow of data updating the truck position and that you can easily grab the trucks coordinate. As such you would only need a function to determine if the truck coordinate is at the end of the route line. You will likely need to account for a margin of error (i.e. within 15 meters of the end of the line) as a single coordinate can represent a single molecule with enough decimal places and GPS devices typically have an accuracy of +/- 15 meters. With this in mind all you would need to do is calculate the distance from the truck coordinate to the last coordinate of the route line. For example:

```
var lastRouteCoord = [-110, 45];
var truckCoord = [-110.0001, 45.0001];

var minDistance = 15;

//Get the distance between the coordinates (by default this function returns a distance in meters).
var distance = atlas.math.getDistanceTo(lastRouteCoord, truckCoord);

if(distance <= minDistance){
    //Open popup.
    //Examples: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html#Popups
}
```